# Angular.js compiled directive template to string in controller - better way?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, leaflet

I'm using the [Angular Leaflet Directive](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive) and want to dynamically populate the pop up content.

To populate the content, you can assign an html string to a property called "messages".
[Example shown here.](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/main-marker)

I want to use a directive templateUrl to create the dynamic content, convert it to an HTML string and assign it to the messages property in the controller.

I accomplished this but my solution seems overly complex to me.  Is there a better way?

[See my plunkr solution here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQPj4f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I decided to ditch the idea of a dynamically populated popup message and will be routing to a separate view which will slide up on a click event.

I'll be using nested views with [angular-ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

[Examples of Leaflet events with angular directive.](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/events)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for your question here. https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/238
Using ng-include in the popup content.